# remove text in input value jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, keyword

I've a form with an empty `input#tags`.
I have a `p#list_tags` with few `span.keyword`.
When I click a `.keyword`, its text append to `input.val()`
But I can't remove its text from `val()` if I click on it again.
My code :

```
$("p#list_tags span.keyword").click(function() {
    var tag = $(this).text();
    var tags = $("#tags").val();

    if($(this).hasClass('selected_tag')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected_tag');
        // Here, I don't know what to do... I've tried this, but...
        // $("#tags").remove(":contains('" + tag + "')");
    }
    else {
        $("#tags").val(tags + ' ' + tag);
        $(this).addClass('selected_tag');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("p#list_tags span.keyword").click(function() {
    var tag = $(this).text();
    var tags = $("#tags").val();

    if($(this).hasClass('selected_tag')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected_tag');

        //if that tag is last one, we need to append space before tag
        var res = tags.split(" "); 
        var replaceString = "";
        if(res[res.length-1] == tag){
          replaceString = " " + tag;
        }else{
          replaceString = tag + " ";
        }

        $("#tags").val(tags.replace(replaceString, "")); // Replace with empty value
    }
    else {
        $("#tags").val(tags + ' ' + tag);
        $(this).addClass('selected_tag');
    }
});
```